# Ansible: Pass a variable gererated in a role af a host1 to another role of a host2

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use a variable generated in a role for a host1 and use it in another role for a host2.

This is the general layout used:

```
|   # Group variables
+-- group_vars
|   +-- all  # variables set on all hosts 

|   # Collection of playbooks divided by *role*
+-- roles
   - role-nfs.yml   # playbook for role `role-nfs`
|  - role-app.yml  # playbook for role `role-app`
|  - role-app      # directory containing stuff used by `role-app`
|  - role-nfs       # directory containing stuff used by `role-nfs`   
|
+-- site.yml
|   # This is the main playbook.
```

The variable is generated for host1: `nfs` in `role-nfs/task/main.yml`

```
- name: Export nfs_server_ip to a host-fact type variable
  set_fact:
    nfs_server_ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    cacheable: True
```

Then grabbed by the host2: `app` in `role-app.yml` playbook:

---

```
- name: Deploy app
  tags:
    - app
  hosts: app
  roles:
    - role: role-app
      nfs: True
      nfs_ip: "{{hostvars['nfs_server_ip']}}"
```

And passed to the `role-app/task/main.yml`. But debugging info tells me I get an empty string:

```
- debug:
    msg: "This is nfs_ip: {{nfs_ip}} "
```

out:

```
TASK [app : debug] *********************************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/playbooks/roles/role-app/tasks/main.yml:26
ok: [app001] => {
"msg": "This is nfs_ip:  "
}
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. Any help?

### EDIT

So I managed to get what I need, i.e. `nfs_ip` in such a way:

```
      group_name_nfs: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['groups']['nfs-server'][0]}}"
      nfs_ip: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['cluster']['nodes'][group_name_nfs]['ips'][0]}}"
```

There may be a better way of doing it..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [in-memory inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html).

```
- name: Add nfs_server_ip to in-memory inventory.
  add_host:
    hostname: nfs-server
    public_ip: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
```

And later use something like the following

```
- name: Deploy app
  tags:
    - app
  hosts: app
  roles:
    - role: role-app
      nfs: True
      nfs_ip: "{{ hostvars['nfs-server']['public_ip'] }}"
```

Comment: In-memory inventory, as its name suggests, is stored **in memory**. How would it survive after the first playbook finished running?

Comment: I don't get it. According to your scheme you have 1 playbook (site.yml) with different roles. Isn't it?

Comment: I only see what OP wrote in the question. They call `role-app.yml` a playbook (and given the posted code there is no doubt it is one). And they use fact caching for preserving facts between different playbook runs.　It might make little sense, but I can't see how using an in-memory inventory would improve or even fit the scenario.

Comment: As far as I have understood role-app.yml it's a role not a playbook. But anyway OP should clarify that moment

Comment: It is posted in the question. What's there to understand? Ensure yourself by examining the code.　Even if it was not, there would be no need to use the in-memory inventory, the hosts are prescribed.　What problem does your answer solve?

Comment: It solves the OP question - "How to pass a variable gererated in a role af a host1 to another role of a host2"

Comment: Why the in-memory inventory would be necessary to do it? All you do is use `hostvars` magic variable to access another host fact. In your code it is called `nfs-server`. Why is it required? You can access that other host fact with `hostvars['other_host']` without using the in-memory inventory.　Kindly please do not neglect my question by writing inconsistent "it solves the OP question" (a question cannot be solved) and do answer what technical problem does your answer solve.

Comment: And why not? Do you know any negative effects of using in-memory inventories?

Comment: So you admit it does not solve any problem and has no meaning. Thank you.　Regarding negative effects: read my first comment. After playbook execution ends it is lost. OP uses fact caching because they want facts to be accessible in another playbooks.

Comment: ```So you admit it does not solve any problem and has no meaning``` it solves op problem - in-memory variables survive between playbooks